# Реализация поиска точки пересечения многочлена и окружности с помощью БИНАРНОГО ПОИСКА. Язык С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, график, бинарный-поиск

Дано следующее задание:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение должно основываться на бинарном поиске. Моя реализация задачи (логика - находим значение в точке графика многочлена, подставляем его в окружность и сравниваем с квадратом радиуса):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const long double EPS = 1e-14;


long double f(long double x, vector<long double>& coeffs) {

    long double x2 = x * x;
    long double x3 = x2 * x;
    long double x4 = x2 * x2;

    return coeffs[4] * x4 + coeffs[3] * x3 +
        coeffs[2] * x2 + coeffs[1] * x + coeffs[0];
}

long double circle(long double x, long double xx, long double yy, long double rad, vector<long double>& coeffs)
{
    return pow((x - xx), 2) + pow((f(x, coeffs) - yy), 2);
}

int main() {

    long double center_x, center_y, radius;
    int n;
    long double x;

    cin >> center_x >> center_y >> radius;

    cin >> n;

    vector<long double> coeffss(n + 1, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> coeffss[i];
    }
    reverse(coeffss.begin(), coeffss.end());

    vector<long double> coeffs(5, 0);
    copy(coeffss.begin(), coeffss.end(), coeffs.begin());

    cin >> x;

    long double l = x;
    long double r = radius;
    long double mid;
    
    while (r - l > EPS) {

         mid = (l + r) / 2;
        if (circle(mid, center_x, center_y, radius, coeffs) < pow(radius, 2))
            l = mid;
        else if (circle(mid, center_x, center_y, radius, coeffs) > pow(radius, 2))
            r = mid;
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    cout << fixed << setprecision(16);
    cout << mid;
}
```

Во время выполнения тестов наблюдается следующая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема алгоритма? Если необходимо - ссылка на задачу - https://stepik.org/lesson/311541/step/3?unit=293969

Comment: upd. Изменение правой границы на 5 позволило добиться того, что не проходит теперь лишь 5 тест. Но что делать дальше - всё ещё не знаю.

Comment: upd. Изменение правой границы на 10 позволило добиться того, что всё прошло. Не хочу больше заниматься спортпрогой.

Comment: А где у вас проверялось расстояние от точки до окружности? Нигде. Так что хреново они решения тестируют

Comment: Мда, дожились... Пересечение *многочлена* с *окружностью*... Математики ЕГЭшные...

Comment: Блин... Очевидно же, что раз начальная точка внутри окружности, то второй для бинарного поиска должна быть точка вне окружности. Ну так и надо ее брать за пределами окружности. Например, по x большей, чем c_d+c_x.

Comment: Понятно же, что функции, которую представляет многочлен, люди вокруг вас не такие идиоты, все мы можем допустить описку.

Comment: Пересекаться может *график*, но не сама функция или многочлен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного времени появилось, захотелось набросать... Там основная проблема - подобрать точность вывода такую, чтоб и хватило, и не зациклило программу из-за машинной неточности...

```
using namespace std;

double cx, cy, r, eps = 1e-10;
double a[5];

double fnc(double x) { return (((a[4]*x+a[3])*x+a[2])*x+a[1])*x + a[0]; }
double sqr(double x) { return x*x; }
double tgt(double x) { return sqr(x-cx) + sqr(fnc(x)-cy) - sqr(r); }

int main()
{
    int n; double x;
    cin >> cx >> cy >> r >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) cin >> a[n-i];
    cin >> x;

    double left = cx - 2*r, right = x;
    double fl = tgt(left), fr = tgt(right);
    if (fl*fr > 0) return 1; // Но нам гарантируют, что это не произойдет!
    while( right - left > eps )
    {
        x = (left + right)/double(2.0);
        if (fl * tgt(x) < 0) right = x;
        else                  left = x;
    }
    cout << fixed << setprecision(10) << x;
}
```